# Schema.org 'amenityFeature' under Hotel is not recognized by Google

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool, json-ld

I'm developing the [schema.org](http://schema.org/) vocabulary for a hotel webpage (see [markup for hotels](http://schema.org/docs/hotels.html)).
As per schema.org directives, under `Hotel` I can add a `amenityFeature` but the Google testing tool throws an exception telling me that property is not recognized by Google.

Here the JSON-LD I've been created:

```json
  {
  "hasMap": "https:\/\/www.google.com\/maps\/@41.380061,2.175798,10z",
  "amenityFeature": [
    {
      "name": "Wi-fi",
      "value": true,
      "@type": "LocationFeatureSpecification"
    },
    {
      "name": "Garaje",
      "value": true,
      "@type": "LocationFeatureSpecification"
    },
    {
      "name": "Se admiten animales +5kg",
      "value": true,
      "@type": "LocationFeatureSpecification"
    },
    {
      "name": "Se admiten animales -5kg",
      "value": true,
      "@type": "LocationFeatureSpecification"
    },
    {
      "name": "Aparcamiento",
      "value": true,
      "@type": "LocationFeatureSpecification"
    },
    {
      "name": "Accesible para personas de movilidad reducida",
      "value": true,
      "@type": "LocationFeatureSpecification"
    },
    {
      "name": "Caja fuerte (Servicios de pago)",
      "value": true,
      "@type": "LocationFeatureSpecification"
    },
    {
      "name": "Recepci\u00f3n 24h",
      "value": true,
      "@type": "LocationFeatureSpecification"
    },
    {
      "name": "Aire acondicionado en zonas comunes",
      "value": true,
      "@type": "LocationFeatureSpecification"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ascensor",
      "value": true,
      "@type": "LocationFeatureSpecification"
    },
    {
      "name": "Internet por cable",
      "value": true,
      "@type": "LocationFeatureSpecification"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cobertura tel\u00e9fonos m\u00f3viles",
      "value": true,
      "@type": "LocationFeatureSpecification"
    }
  ],
  "@context": "http:\/\/schema.org",
  "@type": "Hotel",
  "@id": "http:\/\/localhost\/hotels\/details.aspx?UID=GHU\/JP151029",
  "name": "Roma Reial",
  "image": "http:\/\/photos.hotelbeds.com\/giata\/00\/000423\/000423a_hb_a_001.jpg",
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "PLA\u00c7A REIAL,11  , 08002, BARCELONA, BARCELONA 08002",
    "postalCode": "08002"
  },
  "url": "http:\/\/localhost\/hotels\/details.aspx?UID=GHU\/JP151029",
  "geo": {
    "latitude": 41.380061,
    "longitude": 2.175798,
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates"
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: (Similar question on Stack Overflow: [*Testing Tool Reports - “The type Apartment is not a type known to Google”*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38954083/1591669).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the Hotel-related types and properties were introduced with [version 3.1](https://schema.org/docs/releases.html#v3.1), which was released two weeks ago.

It seems that Google didn’t update their SDTT yet. I would expect that it will recognize the new types/properties soon.

Comment: Thank you very much @unor for your answer! Kind regards!